# What are the benefits of using vite.config.ts instead of vite.config.js

Tags: typescript, vite

Vite's documentation says that you can use `vite.config.js` or `vite.config.ts` for the configuration's file. Tried to add `vite.config.ts` to `tsconfig` so I could perform a type checking in the file itself, but ended up having several strange errors as that file is not really part of the project. So... what's the point of having a Vite TS configuration file (instead of JS) if it cannot be type checked?

PS: The "strange errors" are:

```
node_modules/vite-plugin-html/dist/index.d.ts:2:38 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'ejs'

node_modules/vite-plugin-html/dist/index.d.ts:3:25 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'html-minifier-terser'

vite.config.ts:25:50 - error TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type '(options: LoadCssModuleFileOptions) => Plugin<any>'

vite.config.ts:32:14 - error TS7006: Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type

...
```

Comment: I think you'd better ask how to resolve these "strange errors" instead of "what are the benefits". Apparently, the benefit is that it can be type-checked.

Comment: Yes, apparently, but how is that done? For me is clear that `vite.config.ts` is not part of the project files (to be built), so it doesn't have to be included in the `tsconfig` (hence the errors if you do it). But then... `vite.config.ts` doesn't need to be compiled, only interpreted by Vite, but Vite doesn't do type-checking,... so you would need to do a separate type checking only for `vite.config.ts`?? Sure I'm missing something.

Comment: You need to provide more details about these "strange errors". But being included in `tsconfig.json` does not mean it will be compiled. Especially when you are using Vite, what is to be compiled is handled by Vite.

Comment: I added a list of some of the errors reported by `tsc`.

Comment: These seem like resolvable type errors. Please also post a (minimal reproducible) `vite.config.ts`. Also please modify your question title.